# Filter results with not like

Tags: soql, query, sosl

I have to query task object to get the rows with subject not starting with 'Email' .

I have tried the given query. But it is not working . Please suggest.

```
select status, subject, whatId from task where subject  != 'Email:%'
```

also, there is nothing like `NOT LIKE` that I can use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try the following query

```
select status, subject, whatId from task where NOT subject LIKE 'Email:%'
```